# can one hypothesis be derived from another hypothesis?

Tags: publications, research-process, independent-researcher, terminology, theory

I have a theory and hypothesis indicating that *X* leads to *Y*. The analysis proves this wrong, I want to say that it is possible to reformulate theory and hypothesis and show that *Y* leads to *X*. Can I say that the second hypothesis was derived from the first? And if so, is there a name for such type of hypotheses?

Comment: I don't think there is a name

Comment: In math one uses the terminology "conditional" in this situation, e.g. "Theorem A is conditional on the Riemann Hypothesis." This means that the proof of A uses the RH at some point.

Answer (score 1):

The implication B→A is called the *converse* of the implication A→B. Note that "all A's are B's" is in effect the implication "if x is an A, then x is a B", so loosely speaking it makes sense to say that "all B's are A's" is the converse of "all A's are B's".

Of course, this is not quite the same as your original example of "A leads to B" vs. "B leads to A", but it is close enough that the same terminology might make sense.